# Can't figure out how to align elements using grid-template-areas

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website as a school project and am having difficulties getting the grid-template-area to work. I used the same method on the main index that this is being extended to for the header and it worked fine, so I'm not sure why it doesn't want to for this.

It should give me an area with the Image and Info being one next to the other while the description is under it, but instead it has them all one under another like it is without any CSS formatting

```
{% extends "_global/index.html" %}

{% block main %}

<div class="book-info">

    <img src="{{book.book_id}}.jpg" alt="{{ book.name|escape }}" height="300" width="200" class="book-image">

    <div class="book-info-1">
        <h1>{{ book.name|escape }}</h1>
        <h3>Original name: {{ book.original_name⁯ }}</h3>
        <p>Authors: </p>

        {% for authors in authorName %}
        <a href="/goranPL/author/{{ authors.author_id }}">
            {{ authors.first_name }}
            {{ authors.last_name }}
        </a>
        </br>
        {% endfor %}

        <p>Publisher: <a href="/goranPL/publisher/{{ book.publisher_id }}">{{ publisher.name }}</a></br></p>
        <p>Publishing year: {{ book.publishing_year }}</p>
        <p>Nr of pages: {{ book.pages }}</p>
        <p>ISBN: {{ book.isbn }}</p>
        <p>Book language: {{ book.language|escape }}</p>

        Genres:
        {% for name in bookName %}
        <a href="/goranPL/genre/{{ name.genre_id }}">
            </br>
            {{ name.name }}

        </a>
        {% endfor %}

        <p>
            Last book placement: <a href="/goranPL/bookPlacement/book/{{ book.book_id }}">
                {{bookPlacement.placed_at}}</a></br>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="book-description">
    <p>Description: {{ book.description|escape }}</p>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

```
.book-info {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "image       info"
        "description description"
        "description description"
}

.book-image {
    grid-area: image;
}

.book-info-1 {
    grid-area: info;
    text-align: left;
}

.book-description {
    grid-area: description;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that when you copy/pasted your CSS you clipped off the first line that should be `.book-info {`.  Otherwise, if it isn't in the original code you will get the behavior you describe.

Also, looks like your book description div is outside of the book-info div.  It would need to be inside since the book-info div defines the grid template.

Comment: It looks fine with dummy content, meaning there is probably something wrong with the values being populated. Maybe they are breaking the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what changed, but after starting the server again on the following day without any changes besides moving the description into the main div it worked perfectly.